# Possible to pause debugger immediately after onclick event?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, debugging, onclick, breakpoints

I am trying to fix a bug in someone else's code. The program has the following dynamically created onclick event:

```
function onclick(event)
{
javascript:initpage(164725) 
}
```

This code only exists when the program is run. The error message is "JavaScript runtime error: 'initpage' is undefined". This is occurring because the initpage function definition is spelt InitPage, so I am trying, without success, to locate where in the code InitPage is being dynamically changed to lower case.

I cannot get any breakpoints to hit after clicking the event.

Is it possible to pause the debugger immediately after the onclick event so that I can follow the code? If not, what are my options? thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** 
override onclick, something like this

```js
window.onload= function()
{    
   var spans = document.getElementById('breadCrumbsID').getElementsByTagName('span');


for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {   
    spans[i].setAttribute('onclick',"javascipt:InitPage();")
}
}

function InitPage()
{
   console.log("it worked");
}
```

```html
<div id="breadCrumbsID">   
    <span id="sp1" onclick="javascript:initpage()"> A</span>
    <span id="sp2" onclick="javascript:initpage()"> B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "JavaScript runtime error: 'initpage' is undefined" means this function does not exist and you are saying there is another "InitPage()" availble. If it is spell mistake and you can't change dynamic code then simplly overrride like above in the window.onload function.

Comment: The code gives the following error: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference